# replace control characters in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, character-encoding

This is [a small text](https://db.tt/Hof5LQeM):

> What\222s with All the Parentheses?

In Emacs `\222` above is shown as a control character (in red). It is supposed to be `'`, but I don't understand why it is `\222` instead, even though I know the text was probably generated from OCR?

I can search for the control character `\222` by

```
C-s C-q 2 2 2
```

But I can't when I try to replace it with `'` in a similar way:

```
M-% 
C-q 2 2 2
'
```

So I wonder how to do the replacement? Is it unnecessary to do the replace? Thanks.

Comment: Selecting the offending char with the mouse, C-w (kill-ring-save), invoking M-% (query-replace), and C-y (yank) will put the evil char in the copy/replace buffer. Then type in whatever you want to replace it with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\222` in the [CP-1252 character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is `’`, i.e. U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK in Unicode.

To instruct Emacs that the file is in the CP-1252 encoding, run `C-x RET r` ([`revert-buffer-with-coding-system`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Coding.html#index-revert_002dbuffer_002dwith_002dcoding_002dsystem-1634)) and select `cp1252`. To then save the file in UTF-8 (the de facto standard encoding on Linux and other unix systems), run `C-x RET f` ([`set-buffer-file-coding-system`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Coding.html#index-set_002dbuffer_002dfile_002dcoding_002dsystem-1629)) and select `utf-8`.

You should be able to replace `\222` by `'`, but it's possible that this isn't matching because Emacs is using different coding systems under the hood for the buffer content and for the search, because `\222` is an invalid character in the default encoding that Emacs guessed (latin1). This problem will be resolved if you declare the correct encoding (and `\222` will be displayed as `’`). If you want to replace the character without doing anything to tell Emacs about the encoding, copy-paste the character from the buffer to the search string.

Comment: Thanks! Given a pair of a character and its code, how can we find out which charset(s) might have that? For example how do you find out which charset(s) that have `\222` encode `'`?

Comment: Converting the charset works for me. With original text, it is strange that I can search for `\222` by `C-s C-p 2 2 2 RET`, but can't replace it with `'` by `M-% RET C-p 2 2 2 RET '`.

Comment: (1) Does Emacs always open a text file with utf-8? Does it try to guess the encoding method for a text file? (2) How can we find out the current encoding method that Emacs uses to open a text file in a buffer?

Comment: @Tim To find out the charset: guesswork. There aren't many likely possibilities anyway: Latin1, CP1252 and Unicode are the most likely for American and Western European users. For how Emacs guesses the encoding, [see the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recognize-Coding.html#Recognize-Coding).